# Bash Start and Stop Scripts

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script that starts a number of different widgets (various Rails applications) and runs them in the background. I'm now trying to write a complimenting stop script that kills each of the processes started by that start script, but I'm not sure of the best way to approach it.

Following is my start script:

```
#!/bin/bash

widgets=( widget1 widget2 widget3 ) # Specifies, in order, which widgets to load
port=3000
basePath=$("pwd")

for dir in "${widgets[@]}"
do
  cd ${basePath}/widgets/$dir
  echo "Starting ${dir} widget."
  rails s -p$port &
  port=$((port+1))
done
```

If possible, I was trying to avoid saving the PIDs to a .pid file because they're horribly unreliable. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: There are many powerful, usable, and mature pre-existing tools for this; I personally use forever: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Comment: @Kiyura is right; tools about for this sort of thing. `Bluepill` is one that comes to mind. What do you find unreliable about using `.pid` files?

Comment: @Faiz if a process ends unexpectedly, the PID file isn't cleaned up.

Comment: @Kiyura I'm not opposed to a tool like forever, but I'm hoping not to have a dependency on another tool since I'm not the only developer on the project. In other words, I don't want to complicate the process of getting a development environment configured. ;-)

Comment: @senfo Agreed, but that's an issue that's taken for granted - almost everything under `/etc/init.d` deals with stuff like that. I'd read the PID file on startup (if it exists), check if the process is currently running, and if so, refuse to start with a warning.

Comment: @Faiz Good point about init.d...I'm looking into Bluepill, by the way. It's another dependency, but it looks pretty nice.

Comment: @senfo Also check out `monit`. Similar, but written in C. NOte that both tools require you to specify a PID file! The good thing is that they handle it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep extra dependencies at a minimum and ensure I didn't shut down rails instances that don't belong to me, I ended up going with the following:

**Start Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

widgets=( widget1 widget2 widget3 ) # Specifies, in order, which widgets to load
port=3000
basePath=$("pwd")
pidFile="${basePath}/pids.pid"

if [ -f $pidFile ];
then
  echo "$pidFile already exists. Stop the process before attempting to start."
else
  echo -n "" > $pidFile

  for dir in "${widgets[@]}"
  do
    cd ${basePath}/widgets/$dir
    echo "Starting ${dir} widget."
    rails s -p$port &
    echo -n "$! " >> $pidFile
    port=$((port+1))
  done
fi
```

**Stop Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

pidFile='pids.pid'

if [ -f $pidFile ];
then
  pids=`cat ${pidFile}`

  for pid in "${pids[@]}"
  do
    kill $pid
  done

  rm $pidFile
else
  echo "Process file wasn't found. Aborting..."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use `pkill` with the `-f` switch that is described thus in the man page:

```
-f     The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

Hence, if you want to kill `rails s -p3002`, you can proceed as follows:

```
pkill -f 'rails s -p3002'
```